# I'm learning Javascript, I'm trying to find out why my "Rock paper scissors" game wont work . .

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so I'm sure this code is FILLED with inaccuracies, but I got really confused when I finished this lesson on the CodeAcademy website and then tried to copy/paste it into my own javascript.html file (where I keep stuff I'm learning) and the code wouldn't work! Then I plugged it in to jsfiddle to play with it and still couldn't get it to work.

here is the original code that I copy/pasted from CodeAcademy:

http://jsfiddle.net/p46pnwvx/

**Javascript:**

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} 

console.log("Player: " + userChoice);
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "Rock Wins!";
        }
        else  {
            return "Paper Wins!";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "Paper Wins!";
        }
        else {
            return "Scissors win!";
        }
    }
    else if (choise1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            return "Scissors win!";
        }
        else {
            return "Rock wins!";
        }
    }
}

console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

When this loads, the PROMPT box comes up, but nothing else happens.

Here is what I was playing around with, trying to make the game start and reset with a button, which I thought would be more useful (and educational) than having a game just up and start on it's own.

http://jsfiddle.net/o9ckcy52/

**HTML**

```
<h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors Game!</h1>

        <button id="start" type="button" onclick="startGame()">Wanna Play?</button>
<p id="choice"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
function startGame(){

        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Play again?"; // reset's button
        return prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

        var userChoice = startGame(); // stores result of startGame as user's choice
        var computerChoice = Math.random(); // randomly creates computer's choice
        if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
            computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
            computerChoice = "paper";
        } else {
            computerChoice = "scissors";
        } 

        function compare(choice1, choice2) { //compares user's choice and computer's choice
            if (choice1 === choice2) {
                return "The result is a tie!";
            }
            else if (choice1 === "rock") {
                if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                    return "Rock Wins!";
                }
                else  {
                    return "Paper Wins!";
                }
            }
            else if (choice1 === "paper") {
                if (choice2 === "rock") {
                    return "Paper Wins!";
                }
                else {
                    return "Scissors win!";
                }
            }
            else if (choise1 === "scissors") {
                if (choice2 === "paper") {
                    return "Scissors win!";
                }
                else {
                    return "Rock wins!";
                }
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML= // prints user and computer selections
        "Player: " + userChoice + /r
        "Computer: " + computerChoice;

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = // prints result of selection comparisons
            (compare(userChoice, computerChoice));

    }
```

Here the html works, but nothing happens when you click the button.

Any help given would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to work for me. Are you sure you are looking at the [console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)?

Comment: function `startGame` calls `startGame` again. Is it ok?

Comment: I found a mistype in your JavaScript code: choise1 instead of choice at line 34

Comment: Click the jsHint button under jsFiddle, it will highlight some of the issues

Comment: It looks like startGame() returns before any of the other code is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your code. There were just some minor issues that were fixed. For example, the `userChoice` should be assigned to the prompt. Also, your regex `/r` is invalid and should also be wrapped in quotes, which becomes `"\r"`. You also mispelled one of your `choice1`'s.

**Run the snippet below:**

```js
function startGame() {
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Play again?"; // reset's button
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    var computerChoice = Math.random(); // randomly creates computer's choice
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }

    function compare(choice1, choice2) { //compares user's choice and computer's choice
        if (choice1 === choice2) {
            return "The result is a tie!";
        } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "Rock Wins!";
            } else {
                return "Paper Wins!";
            }
        } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "Paper Wins!";
            } else {
                return "Scissors win!";
            }
        } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "paper") {
                return "Scissors win!";
            } else {
                return "Rock wins!";
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML = // prints user and computer selections
    "<pre>" +
    "Player: " + userChoice + "\r" +
    "Computer: " + computerChoice +
    "</pre>";

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = // prints result of selection comparisons
    (compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
}

document.getElementById("start").onclick = startGame;
```

```html
<h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors Game!</h1>

<button id="start">Wanna Play?</button>
<p id="choice"></p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much. However, the "\r" doesn't work, both the player choice and computer choice prints on the same line. If we could just fix that this would pretty much do what I wanted it to. @boombox

Comment: no problem! i updated my solution. it should work now. I added the "<pre>" tags.

Comment: Actually, I managed to make it work by putting a "</br>" in there, and it worked just fine. Don't know if I'm SUPPOSED to do that, but it seems to be working . . . However I've been playing with it a bit more and now my code won't put out anything but Rock for userChoice, no matter what's actually put in. I wanted to plug in behaviors for if someone "cancels" out of the box and to restrict answers to either rock, paper or scissors.  I've put my updates in my JSfiddle. Can you help me with that here, or should I start a new question?

Comment: Sure, I can help. Post your jsfiddle.

Comment: BY THE WAY! (meant to ask) What do `<pre></pre>` tags do? Also, while going through my code, I found that line at the bottom `document.getElementById("start").onclick = startGame;` What is this doing? Since `startGame` isn't followed by `( )`, it wouldn't be treated as a function, would it?

Comment: `<pre></pre>` just represents pre-formated text. that means whitespace and other characters are displayed as typed. `document.getElementById("start").onclick = startGame;` just assigns the `startGame` function to the onclick listener. `startGame` is a reference to the function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Comment: I made my fixes. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o9ckcy52/8/. Notice the changes I made. For example, I created a while loop when a user enters an invalid entry. Also, the  `( )` around `compare(userChoice, computerChoice)` is unnecessary.

Comment: So does that replace my `<button onClick="startGame()">` (rendering it useless) or is it supposed to work _in addition to_ the button code? Because I notice you never mentioned to remove it, so I never did. I'm assuming that button is actively doing something?

Comment: the `onclick` attribute on your `<button>` functions the same way as setting the `onclick` property in JS, so it replaces it. It's normally a good idea to separate out the concerns between HTML and JS.

Comment: OK! so I was pretty close, wasn't I? Change the `!=` to `!==`, add `userChoice = ` to the prompt verifier, change `== "rock"` to `=== "rock"`, change `else if` to `while` (which I was just about to look up, I knew it was needed) and got rid of the extra `( )` around `compare(userChoice etc)` 
Thank you so much for your help! You've been most informative and I've learned quite a bit =)

Comment: no problem! im glad to help. let me know if you have any other q's.

Answer (score 1):

1- Use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to clean up your js code, you are mixing Spaces and Tabs. Also it will clean your code alignment.

2- `return prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");`

will always return before any code get's executed.

3- You are calling `startGame()` from the button click right? then why you are calling it again from inside the function it self?

Which indicates that you have a missing closing bracket } for the function.

```
var userChoice = startGame();
```